# Salesforce Lookup Filter Issue

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I have the following custom objects all related by `Master-Detail` relationships:
[image]

I would like to create a Lookup Filter on the `StateEntity` field of an `Invoice Item` to only show `StateEntity`s that belong to the account of the `Invoice`.

For some reason, I can select the `Account` of the `Entity` of the `StateEntiy` in the first crieteria:
[image]

but I can only go 1 level above the `Invoice Item` to the `Invoice` instead of 2 levels above the `StateEntity`:
[image]

Why can't I traverse the parent objects the same way from each side?

(I'm logged in as a sysadmin and have full read/write permissions and have enabled "Enhanced Lookups" on all objects.)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new Lookup Field, in Step 2 ("Choose the related object") try to select "Invoice Item" instead of "Invoice". Then in Step 3 if you create a new Lookup Filter you will be able to select "Invoice Item > Invoice > Account".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Greg, I don't think you'll be able to do what you'd like to.  From Salesforce documentation [Notes on Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&language=en_US) - "Spanning Relationships in Lookup Filters" section:

`Filter criteria can include fields directly related to the target object (one level only).`